# How can I center content in a Bootstrap modal box

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Being upfront, I am terrible at CSS. My problem is I'm trying to center an image in a Bootstrap modal box that is centered on mobile and desktop and for the life of me, can't get it to work. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru9b0.png)

Comment: Can you provide your code and what have you tried already?

Comment: Apply inline css to your Bootstrap modal body <div class="modal-body"  style="text-align:center">

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing what you are looking for:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal with a centered image</h2>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://picsum.photos/id/7/250/150" width="250" height="150">
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT** Adding a snippet to answer the comment about how can a flipcard instead of an image be centered.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal with a centered flipcard</h2>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="flip-card" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <div class="flip-card-inner">
              <div class="flip-card-front">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1005/300/300" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
              </div>
              <div class="flip-card-back">
                <h1>John Doe</h1> 
                <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
                <p>We love that guy</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is awesome, thanks so much!! Buuut, If I had a CSS flip card from here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp   How could I center that?

Comment: Same as with the image `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`, apply that to flip-card div. The only difference is that you don't need `display: block` since div is already a block level element. I'll update my answer to provide you with a snippet for that as well.